# Twitter module and posting to twitter

Tags: social-network, users

I have two questions about [twitter](https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter) module.

I want to hide global twitter account from `twitter_account_list_form`, because authenticate user can delete global account, and i want to stop him.

I try with this in form_alter

```
    $pom_array = array_keys($form['accounts']);
        foreach ($pom_array as $key => $val) {
            if (is_int($val)) {
                if ($form['accounts'][$val]['#account']->is_global == 1 )
                    $form['accounts'][$key]['#prefix'] = '<div style="display:none;">';
                    $form['accounts'][$key]['#suffix'] = '</div>';
             }
        }
```

but without success.

And if node has option post to twitter.com, I want to hide that option also because authenticate can change message. I want in that case to post message for global and user's twitter account, if user already connected account with twitter.

Many thanks

Comment: I think you got `$val` and `$key` mixed up a bit especially in the `if()` statement.

Comment: Hi @Baysaa
Yes i made suggested changes but again there is no success
'code'
    $pom_array = array_keys($form['accounts']);
        foreach ($pom_array as $val) {
            if (is_int($val)) {
                if ($form['accounts'][$val]['#account']->is_global == 1 ){
                    $form['accounts'][$val]['#prefix'] = '<div style="display:none;">';
                    $form['accounts'][$val]['#suffix'] = '</div>';
                    }
            }
        }
'code'

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$form['accounts'][$key]` and NOT `$form['accounts'][$val]`?

Comment: here is what is in '$pom_array'
'array(13) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(2) [3]=> string(5) "#tree" [4]=> string(8) "#parents" [5]=> string(14) "#array_parents" [6]=> string(7) "#weight" [7]=> string(10) "#processed" [8]=> string(9) "#required" [9]=> string(11) "#attributes" [10]=> string(14) "#title_display" [11]=> string(3) "#id" [12]=> string(7) "#sorted" } '